# Calling Method represented by string

Tags: javascript

I am being passed a string similar to below.

```
"Users_Controller.login"
```

"Users_Controller" represents the object below.
And "login" a method within it.

```
var Users_Controller = ( function () {
return{

  login : function(vo, callback)
   {......}

 }
 })();
```

Given only the string as a pointer,is it possible call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function getPropertyFromString(str, start) {
    str = str.split(".");
    var prop = start || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if(prop == undefined)
          return prop;
        else
          prop = prop[str[i]];
    }
    return prop;
}
getPropertyFromString("Users_Controller.login");
```

However, this does not allow bracket syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var Users_Controller = (function () {
    return {

        login: function (name) {
            alert("hello " + name);
        },
        logout: function (name) { alert("goodbye "+name); }

    }
})();


var methods = {};

for (method in Users_Controller) {
    methods["Users_Controller." + method] = Users_Controller[method];
}

methods["Users_Controller.login"]('john');
methods["Users_Controller.logout"]('john');
```